# AppleScript checking if folder exists causes “AppleEvent handler failed” error -10000

Tags: applescript

AppleScript on macOS Mojave and can't work out why this script gives the expected "TRUE" on the first folder, but instead of "FALSE" on the second folder it aborts with the error message:

> [error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000 from folder (file "Felix HD:Users:Billy:TESTING:FOLDER2"]

```
tell application "Finder"

    set targetFolder to POSIX file "/Users/Billy/TESTING/FOLDER1" -- Existing folder

    if exists folder targetFolder then
        say "TRUE"
    else
        say "FALSE"
    end if

    set targetFolder to POSIX file "/Users/Billy/TESTING/FOLDER2" -- Non-existing folder

    if exists folder targetFolder then
        say "TRUE"
    else
        say "FALSE"
    end if

end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer: removed the word 'folder' from the if statements and now it works!

If anyone could confirm this is the proper syntax that would be great.

```
tell application "Finder"

    set targetFolder to POSIX file "/Users/Billy/TESTING/FOLDER1" -- Existing folder

    if exists targetFolder then
        say "TRUE" -- result!!
    else
        say "FALSE"
    end if

    set targetFolder to POSIX file "/Users/Billy/TESTING/FOLDER2" -- Non-existing folder

    if exists targetFolder then
        say "TRUE"
    else
        say "FALSE" -- result!!
    end if

end tell
```

Comment: ...and maybe someone could tell me why the "end tell" won't stay pasted in the code box!

Comment: Code formatting is 4 spaces indentation on all lines, not just the first, see edit

Comment: Well done.  Yes, removing the `folder` specifier is the correct solution, and your syntax is good.  You can also say `if the targetFolder exists then` as a more natural-language sounding alternative, but both forms are equally sound.  Preferentially, I'd use _System Events_ to test for a file's (or folder's) existence generally, but I suppose it makes little difference, except that _System Events_ can handle posix paths well.  The other way to test for existence is a bit of a trick, and simply involves coercing to an `alias` inside a `try` block.

Comment: CJK - thanks for the review! I'm trying a System Events version now, but having a different problem using "delete every item of folder targetFolder" which is my real purpose for this script and works in the Finder version.

Comment: Tip: Tag users with `@` and click on the name that appears in order to ensure they are notified of a reply (which I wasn't).  Regarding your second problem, I'd recommend posting a new question with your ultimate objective and the issues you're encountering.  Be warned with _System Events_ that `delete` actually deletes a file or folder, **without** sending it to the trash.

Comment: @CJK -  I’m using the _Finder_ version for now but will work on a _System Events_ version as it would be nice to skip the trash can. I’ll post a new question if I get stuck and thanks for the help.

Comment: The trick would be to use _Finder_ to get the contents of the front _Finder window_, as an `alias list`, which _System Events_ can then delete.